# oracle exercise question in my data using 2 table information

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**person**

```
name   home    st
JAMES  LA      L1
MIKE   BOSTON  B1
ANTON  LA      L1
LEE    NY      N1
BROWN  NY      N2
```

mentor

```
name  m_name
JAMES ANTON
MIKE  (null)
ANTON (null)
LEE   BROWN
BROWN (null)
```

**I want to get information from people who live in the same st and cities as mentors.**

In the example I gave, it is JAMES who meets that condition.
How could I get that information?..

my version oracle11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like two joins:

```
select pn.name
from mentor m join
     person pn
     on pn.name = m.name join
     person pm
     on pm.name = m.m_name
where pn.street = pm.street and pn.city = pm.city;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me a lot! I have a few more questions, so I'm going to post a question, is there any way I can ask you? I'm limited to 5 questions within 24 hours ...